# RSpec Controller Test Failing Method Not Called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm trying to write a simple RSpec test for "UsersController" that tests the index method.

The code for the controller index method looks as follows:

```
# GET /users
# GET /users.json
def index
  @users = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @users }
  end
end
```

I am trying to test that the "all" method is called and that the index view is rendered. Here is my Rspec code for that:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
    describe 'get index', :type => :controller do
        before :each do
          @fake_users = [double('user1'), double('user2')]
        end
        it 'should call the model method that retrieves all Users' do
          User.should_receive(:all).once.and_return(@fake_users)
          get :index
        end
        describe 'after valid search' do
          before :each do
        User.stub(:all).and_return(@fake_users)
        get :index
          end
          it 'should select the index template for rendering' do
        response.should render_template('index')
          end
          it 'should make the users results available to that template' do
        assigns(:users).should == @fake_users
          end
        end
    end
end
```

However, this fails the "get index" test with the following message:

```
Failure/Error: User.should_receive(:all).once.and_return(@fake_users)
       (<User(id: integer, firstname: string, lastname: string, username: string, email: string, password_digest: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) (class)>).all(any args)
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error and the code you are posting say two different things.  Are you using `User.should_receive(:find).with(:all).once.and_return(@fake_users)` or are you using `User.should_receive(:all).once.and_return(@fake_users)` in your test?

Comment: It "should" work. It may seem too simplistic, but is your routing definitely working correctly for `users#index`? (Can browse to it and whatnot?)

Comment: Yeah, what @JTG said...

Comment: Ah, sorry I was just trying different things. I found the problem. I'll post it in an answer. Thanks to both of you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by the UsersController requiring a log in first. So the controller looked like:

```
class UsersController < AuthenticatedController
```

So the path wasn't accessible to RSpec.